# Filter out invalid emails to NOT show up from alert prompts onto document

Tags: javascript

The behavior I want to get is when the user inputs anything invalid(data), to not show up onto the document write as the domain and username since we are using a slice and uppercase in order to manipulate the username only and show the domain.

It works fine when a valid email in entered, but not when erroneous data is entered it still writes it to document.

```
function emailValid(email) {
      var emailRegex = /^[-\w.]+@([A-z0-9][-A-z0-9]+\.)+[A-z]{2,4}$/;
      var valid = email.match(emailRegex);
      return valid;
  }

var email = prompt("Please enter your email address");
                    if (emailValid(email)) {
                        document.write("<p>Thank you for registering with us!</p>");
                    } else {
                        document.write("<p> Error: Please enter a valid email address </p>");   
                        }



var atIndex = email.indexOf('@');
var getString = email.slice(atIndex + 1);
var getUsername = email.slice(0, atIndex);
var valid = getUsername.toUpperCase();
document.write("<p>The domain for this email is " + getString + "</p>");
document.write("<p>The username for this email is " + valid + "</p>");
```

Comment: I'm not sure what your issue is exactly. Your last two `document.write` are not under any condition, so they'll always execute.

Comment: Error: Please enter a valid email address

The domain for this email is gfgfdgfg

The username for this email is GFGFDGF   (this  is the outcome when i type gfgfdgfg) and i dont want that to happen.

Comment: Yes, that's what your code does.

Comment: ok, what needs to be done to not have that show up in the last document write portions but only show the valid inputs?

Comment: Put these statements within your `if (emailValid(email))` condition?

Comment: ok. it worked!!

Answer (score 0):

I took Jetos recommendation and did this:

```
var email = prompt("Please enter your email address");
                    if (emailValid(email)) {
                        var atIndex = email.indexOf('@');
                        var getString = email.slice(atIndex + 1);
                        var getUsername = email.slice(0, atIndex);
                        var valid = getUsername.toUpperCase();
                        document.write("<p>Thank you for registering with us!</p>");
                        document.write("<p>The domain for this email is " + getString + "</p>");
                        document.write("<p>The username for this email is " + valid + "</p>");
                    } else {
                        document.write("<p> Error: Please enter a valid email address </p>");
                    }
```